# How to arrange multiple arrays by a specific field

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that has multiple arrays inside it. I am trying to arrange those arrays from the amount of greatest to least new_sales. Here is the example of the array which goes on for about 40 arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Tech] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Anthony
                    [last_name] => Bisignano
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [new_sales] => 21
                    [upgrades] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Tech] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Arnold
                    [last_name] => Ybanez
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [new_sales] => 5
                    [upgrades] => 0
                )

        )
```

The function I am trying to use is the following:

```
function aasort (&$techs, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($techs);
    foreach ($techs as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$techs[$ii];
    }
    $techs=$ret;
    }

    aasort($test,"new_sales");
```

AM I using this function wrong or is there another approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sorting functions in PHP that support user-defined comparison methods. Code like this should help you get started with that.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[0]['new_sales'] == $b[0]['new_sales']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[0]['new_sales'] < $b[0]['new_sales']);
}
usort($data, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably want to use `usort()` such that you can define your sorting logic.

So something like this:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0]['new_sales'] > $b[0]['new_sales']) {
        return -1; // note we use -1 here because we want a reverse sort
    } else if ($a[0]['new_sales'] < $b[0]['new_sales']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```